# PHP Xdebug, Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller' not found in /

Tags: symfony, xdebug, phpstorm

i am **noob** and i am trying to run xdebug under phpstorm, everytime i get this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller' not found in /home/.../..../src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php on line 15.

In the beginnig i was thinking that is related windows 7+ uniformserver, because i was using this combination. Later i have installed ubuntu linux, lamp, latest xdebug and phpstorm. After this i have tried debugging default symfony project Acme (so i did not change any files), but nothing changed.

Have you ever encountered problem like this? If yes, can you please tell me how can i solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your vendor libraries installed? (do a `composer install` from the command line). Can you paste the code in your controller pls.
Are you getting this error only when trying to run xdebug, or even with xdebug disabled? Also are you using the APC class loader?

Comment: @Pierre, i did not write any code, i get this error even in default symfony project. configure page works properly when i go to browser. I selected interpreter from phpstorm's setting and it sees xdebug there. I dont know what is APC class, as i said i am noob. but it is competely default symfony folder with standart vendors.

Comment: And if you disable XDebug? Does it work then? I assume you are using the latest Symfony release...

Comment: @jperovic, i use 2.4 standart vendors, it works properly, there is no error, i can configure my db via browser (configure page of symfony) with no problem. i did not change anything, any file, any code, its competely default.

Comment: OK, did you run `app_dev.php` or `app.php`? This seems to me like cache error (like @Pierre suggested). Also, try restarting `LAMP` to force `APC` cache resetting

Comment: @Pierre, i am getting only when trying to run xdebug

Comment: Which version of php are you using? If you are on php 5.5, you might need to disable the opcache extension

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have used two javascript methods

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `File | Invalidate caches and restart` and then start the new Composer project?